# Return cells with different cell identifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell with multiple cell Identifiers. I tried the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSString *cellID;
    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0:
            cellID = @"firstCell";
            break;
        case 1:
            cellID = @"secondCell";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
 }
```

When I run the app, it displays the first cell 2 times, even though in the storyboard, there are 2 cells with different objects inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `[indexPath section]` really what you want?
I think you want `[indexPath row]`